# Adding lines into CMakeList.txt makes an error. I need help

Tags: ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Firstly i need to say im totally beginner on ROS.I managed to install it and my Professor wanted to me complete these tasks;

-Create a ROS package with your name.

-Create two nodes, a chatter which publishes std_msgs and a listener
to listen to chatter.

-The message you are required to send will be assigned for each one
separately.

-The listener should get the message and print it using ROS_INFO
function.

So i managed to create work space , but i stucked at somewhere that wants me to add these lines into my_package/CMakeLists.txt.

lines are ;

```
add_executable(name_of_node_chatter src/01.cpp) ,
target_link_libraries(name_of_node_chatter ${catkin_LIBRARIES}) , 
add_dependencies(name_of_node_chatter my_package_generate_messages_cpp)
```

[link text](https://imgur.com/a/nzSajPt)

But when i add them into CMakeList.txt like this ;
[link text](https://imgur.com/a/UnrGv0P)

After i save this txt file i try to run catkin_make command on terminal.It gaves me this error ;
[link text](https://imgur.com/a/Kr1Yo6s)

I don't know what to do , please can you help me to fix this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347349/adding-lines-into-cmakelist.txt-makes-an-error.-i-need-help/) by [Karandiru](https://answers.ros.org/users/52791/karandiru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-03-24**:
Hi, the target you want to build is `name_of_node_listener` or `name_of_node_chatter`? In the screenshot of `CMakeLists.txt` you shared, it's written `name_of_node_listener` but here you wrote `name_of_node_listener`. Could you please add your entire `CMakeLists.txt` to your main question text? You can use the edit button/link for that. It would be easier for people to review. Thank you.

**Comment by [Karandiru](https://answers.ros.org/users/52791/karandiru/) on 2020-03-24**:
I guess i made huge mistake , without defining the chatter , i put listener code on CMakeList.txt that is why terminal gives me that 01.cpp error. In this case 01.cpp is chatter and 02.cpp is listener one.And im trying to run the code without chatter.Thank you for your answer. @tcchiang and also @nkhedekar

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-03-24**:
@tcchiang can you please update your question with a *copy and paste* of the errors instead of using images? Please see the [Support page](https://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do).

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-03-25**:
@jayess, I'm sorry but I am not the original poster. Please tag @Karandiru, thanks.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-03-25**:
@tcchiang Sorry about that. @Karandiru can you please update your question with a copy and paste of the errors instead of using images?

**Comment by [Karandiru](https://answers.ros.org/users/52791/karandiru/) on 2020-03-25**:
I can not access to the ubuntu right now that is why i can not copy the errors from terminal.I editted the lines.Problem is still same. @jayess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

You should have added those three lines after `find_package()`. The order does matter in `CMakeLists.txt`. Please see  [wiki/catkin - CMakeLists.txt - Overall Structure and Ordering](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering).

I think your package does not contain any messages/services/actions files so you don't really need

```
add_dependencies(name_of_node_chatter my_package_generate_messages_cpp)
```

If you do, you need to add `generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)`. The message generation targets are created by `generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)`. Using `add_dependencies(name_of_node_chatter my_package_generate_messages_cpp)` is to ensure that `my_package_generate_messages_cpp` is built before the `name_of_node_chatter`  target.

If your target depends on other messages/services/actions from other packages, even though your package doesn't build any messages/services/actions at compile time, you should add

```
add_dependencies(name_of_node_chatter ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

More details about `add_dependencies(...)` can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Important_Prerequisites.2BAC8-Constraints).

I think it's always safe to add a dependency on `catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS`.

---

Originally posted by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) with karma: 241 on 2020-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karandiru](https://answers.ros.org/users/52791/karandiru/) on 2020-03-28**:
Hello ,

First of all thank your for your explanatory answer.But eventho i tried with your instructions , terminal gave me another error I dont know how to post a terminal output like a link but this is my CMakeList file i put lines in order like you said [link text](https://imgur.com/a/AR7H0Hv) and this is terminal output of *catkin_make* [link text](https://imgur.com/a/zoxVppr) i hope you can still help me.

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-03-28**:
Hello,
You shouldn't have added the lines inside the `find_package()` function. I couldn't tell you exactly where you should have added because you didn't show the whole contents of `CMakeList.txt`. If you are using the auto-generated `CMakeLists.txt`, then they should be added after `include_directories(...)`. I strongly suggest you really look through [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Building_your_nodes-1) and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Important_Prerequisites.2BAC8-Constraints).

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-03-28**:
You don't need to post a terminal output as a link. Please copy-paste the terminal error messages and the `CMakeList.txt` into your original question, select the lines, and press `ctrl+k` or click the *preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is probably due to having the incorrect ordering of your declarations. The lines that you mention should be added in the BUILD section (it should be somewhere around line #100) in the autogenerated CMakeLists.txt file.

---

Originally posted by [nkhedekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/34897/nkhedekar/) with karma: 138 on 2020-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1